# Laravel 4 Resource Controllers - additional parameter for index action

Tags: laravel, controller, resources

Is there a way to define aditional parameter for index action with which I can control my request to database.

**Example**

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController');
URL: www.somesite.com/photo/newyork
```

So I can get all photos from DB where i have city field value equal to newyork. (or something that will be defined by parameter in URL)
(I know that this will trigger show action, but is there a way ? )

**EDIT**

I want to accomplish reduced set returned from database by using Eloquent ORM and Resource Controllers. 
e.g. All picture names that have city field in database equal to newyork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to accomplish this is to not add another URL segment, but to use a URL/GET parameter. For example `www.somesite.com/photo?city=newyork`. Then you can write a validation rule that `city` is required. This is the most flexible system which will allow you to add additional parameters, as needed, without changing routes in the future. Examples:

```
www.somesite.com/photo?city=newyork&order=name_asc
www.somesite.com/photo?city=newyork&type=donut_shop
www.somesite.com/photo?city=newyork&order=name_asc&type=donut_shop
```

If you're interested more in Resource controllers and/or building API's you should check out [this book](https://leanpub.com/build-apis-you-wont-hate). You'll be able to pick up some good tips.

Comment: You can also get this the "laravel" way with: `Input::get('city')`

Comment: How would you write a validation rule that city is required, with Laravel?